# In Kotlin, how do I create a Kafka ListSerde instance?

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka

It looks like the Serdes class creates a helper function called `ListSerde` and it also happens to be the exact same name as the class itself of `ListSerde`.

Because kotlin instantiates new instances of classes without the `new` keyword, kotlin is having trouble trying to figure out if I need to use the constructor or the static function and I'm not sure how to work around it.

I wish to create a reified helper to make our lives a bit easier (create known efficient Serdes when possible, fallback to a jackson mapper for anything else) so I did this

```
    inline fun <reified T : Any> pick(): Serde<T> = pick(T::class)
    inline fun <reified L : List<E>, reified E : Any> pickList(): Serde<List<E>> = pickList(L::class.java, E::class)

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <T : Any> pick(kClass: KClass<T>): Serde<T> = when (kClass) {
        ByteArray::class -> Serdes.ByteArray() as Serde<T>
        ByteBuffer::class -> Serdes.ByteBuffer() as Serde<T>
        Bytes::class -> Serdes.Bytes() as Serde<T>
        Short::class -> Serdes.Short() as Serde<T>
        Int::class -> Serdes.Integer() as Serde<T>
        Long::class -> Serdes.Long() as Serde<T>
        Float::class -> Serdes.Float() as Serde<T>
        Double::class -> Serdes.Double() as Serde<T>
        String::class -> Serdes.String() as Serde<T>
        UUID::class -> Serdes.UUID() as Serde<T>
        else -> jsonWrapper(kClass)
    }

    fun <L : List<E>, E : Any> pickList(klass: Class<L>, item: KClass<E>) =
        Serdes.ListSerde(klass, pick(item))
```

But I cannot figure out how to create an instance of the Serdes.ListSerde class. How would one go about doing this? Am I doing something else wrong? I'm getting the following error

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
public constructor ListSerde<Inner : Any!, L : (Mutable)List<TypeVariable(Inner)!>!>(listClass: Class<TypeVariable(L)!>!, serde: Serde<TypeVariable(Inner)!>!) defined in org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.ListSerde
public open fun <L : (Mutable)List<TypeVariable(Inner)!>!, Inner : Any!> ListSerde(listClass: Class<TypeVariable(L)!>!, innerSerde: Serde<TypeVariable(Inner)!>!): Serde<(Mutable)List<TypeVariable(Inner)!>!>! defined in org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes
```

---

Updated: 10/12/2023 based on Jorn's feedback

I created in Java a snippet of code

```
public class ListSerdeFactory {
    static public <L extends List<Inner>, Inner> Serde<List<Inner>> create(Class<L> listClass, Serde<Inner> innerSerde) {
        return new Serdes.ListSerde<>(listClass, innerSerde);
    }
}
```

And was able to use that as a way to access the ListSerde instead. I'm unblocked on my problem but I would like a more elegant solution if one exists as this feels a bit strange overall.

Comment: There is no way to disambiguate that as far as I know. Your best bet is to write a Java class that exposes the function you need in a Kotlin-compatible way.